# How do I manage dynamic dependencies with PicoContainer?

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, picocontainer

Say I have two classes A and B, with B depending on A.

```
public class A {}

public class B {
    public B(A a) {}
}
```

It's easy to resolve B in a single PicoContainer.

```
    final MutablePicoContainer root = new PicoBuilder().build();
    root.addComponent(new A());
    root.addComponent(B.class, B.class);
    System.out.println(root.getComponent(B.class));
```

But I'd like to have different instances of `B` for different sessions, with variable instances of `A`.  I'm thinking about something like this.

```
    // during startup
    final MutablePicoContainer root = new PicoBuilder().build();
    root.addComponent(B.class, B.class);

    // later, initialize sessions
    final MutablePicoContainer session = new PicoBuilder(root)
        .implementedBy(TransientPicoContainer.class)
        .build();
    session.addComponent(new A());

    // some request
    System.out.println(session.getComponent(B.class));
```

Above code isn't working, because when asking `session` for a `B` it asks the parent container `root` for it.  `B` is found there, but resolved only within `root` and its parents, leading to an `UnsatisfiableDependenciesException.`

Is there any good way to make this work?  Or is this an anti-pattern, and I'm solving the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: You should better use Spring! It's business proven. So much people have afford with a picoc=>spring migration because pico container was to unstable and buggy...

Comment: I disagree. Pico is a *much* better container than Spring's. The advantage in Spring is its community, not its technology.

Comment: @Ronald - I don't understand exactly what your goal is. Do you want a new A and a corresponding new B to be created for each session? Why not use your "single container" pattern to register A and B in the session container rather than the root?

Comment: @erickson: Yes, a new B for each session, and there can be multiple sessions at the same time.  A single container would work, and would arguably be even more correct.  But the sessions are rather short lived, so I thought it would be better (CPU and memory wise) if there's a "static" parent and multiple "dynamic" transient session containers.  Maybe a proto-container from which each session container is copied would be better, instead of a root/sessions hierarchy that acts like one big container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would register B within the session container as well. Any other dependency of B you can leave in the root container. Assume B has another dependency on C. So you can do the following:

```
// during startup
final MutablePicoContainer root = new PicoBuilder().build();
root.addComponent(C.class, C.class);

// later, initialize sessions
final MutablePicoContainer session = new PicoBuilder(root)
    .implementedBy(TransientPicoContainer.class)
    .build();
session.addComponent(B.class, B.class);
session.addComponent(new A());

// some request
System.out.println(session.getComponent(B.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solving a performance problem that doesn't exist isn't a good approach. Have you done any profiling to verify the problem?

If not, consider doing that first.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable caching on your container (or are you using Pico 1.x)?

Try reading [this](http://www.picocontainer.org/caching.html), maybe disabling the cache is enough to solve this problem.